# Python datatable (or pandas): tricky sorting of data frame based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datatable

INPUT DATA

```
from datatable import dt

C1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
C2 = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'a']

df1 = dt.Frame(C1=C1, C2=C2)
```

df1:

```
   | C1  C2
-- + --  --
 0 | a   b 
 1 | a   c 
 2 | b   a 
 3 | c   a
```

OUTPUT DATA

```
C1 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
C2 = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'a']

df2 = dt.Frame(C1=C1, C2=C2)
```

df2:

```
   | C1  C2
-- + --  --
 0 | a   b 
 1 | b   a 
 2 | a   c 
 3 | c   a
```

Convert datatable object to pandas object:

```
df = df.to_pandas()
```

Question description:

I try to make it as understandable as possible. If any questions arise I am happy to explain more. The sample data contains the unique values 'a', 'b', 'c' in the columns C1 and C2. Each combination of the values in C1 and C2 occurs only once (e.g. C1 = 'a' & C2 = 'b' in the first row of df1). For most combinations there is a 'pair', meaning the inverse combination (in this case to the aforementioned example: C1 = 'b' & C2 = 'a' in the third row). How can I order this data frame that all 'pairs' are next to each other? This desired output is displayed in df2. I prefer to use datatable instead of pandas. But if someone has a solution in pandas it would be equally helpful for me.

I hope this question satisfies SO guidelines. If not I am happy to improve it.
Thank you a lot.

Edit: It seems my sample data was too reductionist. This is a less reductionist data set:

```
C1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
C2 = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'a']
Values = [5, 10, 15, 20]

df1 = dt.Frame(C1=C1, C2=C2, Values=Values)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
>>> from datatable import dt, f, sort, ifelse
>>> df1 = dt.Frame(C1=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
                   C2=['b', 'c', 'a', 'a'], 
                   Values=[5, 10, 15, 20])
>>> df1[:, :, sort(ifelse(f.C1<f.C2, f.C1, f.C2), 
                   ifelse(f.C1<f.C2, f.C2, f.C1))]
   | C1  C2  Values
-- + --  --  ------
 0 | a   b        5
 1 | b   a       15
 2 | a   c       10
 3 | c   a       20

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Here we sort the frame by 2 computed columns, the first is the minimum of C1 and C2, and the second is the maximum of C1 and C2.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for. Do you allow me to use your solution in a follow up question. I make sure you are mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

After we convert to `pandas` , we can try `sort_values` after `numpy.sort`

```
import numpy as np 
df1 = df1.to_pandas()

out = df1.iloc[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1.values,1)).sort_values([0,1]).index]
Out[54]: 
  C1 C2
0  a  b
2  b  a
1  a  c
3  c  a
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting the following error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'. I updated my question to better reflect the real dataset. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

C1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
C2 = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'a']
Values = [5, 10, 15, 20]

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': C1, 'C2': C2, 'Values': Values})
srt = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x[['C1', 'C2']].values)),axis=1)
df.loc[srt.argsort(),:]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting the following error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'. I updated my question to better reflect the real dataset. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I modified the answer